# Аренда DNS сервера

Tags: сервер, dns

Здравствуйте,

Пишу конструктор сайтов, и дошел до момента что клиентам нужно привязывать свои домена к моему сервису.

Пример домена: domain.com
Существует ли где то услуга аренды DNS сервера, чтобы клиенты просто в панели управления доменом вводили мои DNS адреса:
ns1.domain.com
ns2.domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Это похоже, вам контроллер домена поднимать надо. Делается на отдельном сервере, обычно в Windows Server 2003, 2008 или 2012.

Ну, батенька, вы палку-то сильно перегнули... Нафига поднимать виндозный контроллер домена, если можно поднять тот же виндозный DNS. Да и не обязательно это на Виндоуз делать.
Услуга аренды конечно существует:
1) арендуете себе доменное имя мойдомен.рф, Ваше доменное имя вносят на ДНС сервера и сопоставляют его с IP-адресом, на котором будет работать Ваш сервис. Это стандартная ситуация - аналогично делается для сайтов;
2) все то же что и в 1-ом варианте, но поднимаем ДНС еще у себя на арендуемом VPS.
Про аренду целого ДНС сервера пока не слышал, но что в мире не случается, может и такое есть...

> дошел до момента что клиентам нужно привязывать свои домена к моему сервису

Как это должно быть? Дело в том, что далее, Вы указали прямые имена DNS-серверов, а для чего? Какова цель? Может тогда мы поймем, что вам нужно?

Comment: Уважаемый Justicet, я писал "как это надо делать в общем случае", а не про байпасы! Если байпас, то самый простой - руками прописать гугловскй 8.8.8.8, и больше не париться!Насколько мне извыестно, аренда DNS сервера не существует в принципе. Но можно поднять свой собственный.

Comment: И ещё - имена доменов не арендуются, а переходят в вашу собственность, пока вы не перестанете их оплачивать. Это такой юридический нюанс.

Comment: Насчет юридического нюанса: с одной стороны, это как бы и собственность пользователя, а с другой - нет, поскольку ежегодно оплачиваются арендные платежи.  [Вот интересная статья на эту тему](http://www.cmsmagazine.ru/library/items/management/legal-aspects-of-registration-of-domain-names/)  >В частности, против присутствия доменных имен в ч. IV ГК РФ и придания им статуса **средства индивидуализации в рамках института интеллектуальной собственности** выступила Рабоч. группа юристов Координац. центра национальн. домена сети Интернет, РосНИИРОС и RU-CENTER.Вот так вот.

Comment: А поскольку существует такой извратизм (мне как юристу-корпоративщику с более чем 15-ти летним стажем претит именовать это "нюансом") - права собственности, в чистом его виде, на домен не существует! Поймите, если у собственника не существует исключительных прав на его имущество - то у него (имущества) уже совершенно другой правовой статус. Правильнее именовать это арендой, возможно, арендой с исключительными правами арендатора по пользованию имуществом (доменом) в течение срока использования.

Comment: @Anton  Reshin вот Вы можете предположить, зачем в системе топикстартера привязывать домены его клиентов? Я вот пока не могу предположить... Может здесь ошибка (насчет ns-серверов)? И в этом сервисе (системе) надо просто указать домен этого клиента? Ну наподобие того как в Дримуивере указывался домен, пароли-явки и т.п. для работы с сайтом напрямую... Может и здесь такая схема?

Comment: А вы за топикстартера не решайте! Ему виднее, зачем.

Comment: И насчёт своего стажа не гордитесь особенно, у меня - 27 лет, правда, в другом амплуа. (Начинал программистом в 1986-м.)

Comment: > А вы за топикстартера не решайте! Ему виднее, зачем.А я и не решаю. Я предположил о возможности ошибки...> И насчёт своего стажа не гордитесь особенно!Это почему!?    Я его честно отслужил, равно как и Вы, смею предположить, свои 27

Answer (score 0):

Это похоже, вам контроллер домена поднимать надо. Делается на отдельном сервере, обычно в  Windows Server 2003, 2008 или 2012. Но есть контрвопрос - а зачем?

Comment: Между прочим, существует мобильная система отладки сайтов Denwer, это здесь: http://www.denwer.ru/